# Books for high school students starting on college math

Tags: reference-request, big-list

I am a student beginning high school from India. I have recently developed a taste for physics and mathematics. I am doing Lagrangian and Quantum Mechanics in Physics. But my mathematics is not too good. I have just finished the high school course (basic calculus and stuff). Could you help me out and suggest some books for the following topics:

1. Algebra (Linear and Abstract)
2. Analysis (Real and Complex)
3. Combinatorics
4. Geometry and Topology.
5. Number Theory.

Comment: [This](http://hbpms.blogspot.com/) is a decent learning road map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've completed the equivalent of first-year University-level Calculus and want to learn more math for further studies in physics, the following might be helpful:

[Mathematical Methods in the Physical Sciences, 3rd.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471198269) by Mary L. Boas

The table of contents is [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471198269).

At the minimum you should cover this book before moving on to more advance material.

---

For more advance reading material / textbooks, you might find the following also useful:

[How to learn math and physics](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/books.html) by Prof. John Baez;

[The Road to Reality: a complete guide to the laws of the universe](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0679454438) by Prof. Roger Penrose, FRS

---

For textbook suggestions, there are many good ones available on the market, so it will depend on your own likes / dislikes and approach to learning / studying; but some of the well-known and recommended are:

**1. Algebra:**

A. Linear Algebra:

- S. Lang, [Introduction to Linear Algebra, 2nd.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540780602) and [Linear Algebra, 3rd.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441930817)

B. Abstract Algebra:

- G. Birkhoff and S. MacLane, [A Survey of Modern Algebra, 3rd.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0019K4R6S)
- I. N. Herstein, [Topics in Algebra, 2nd.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471010901)

**2. Analysis:**

A. Real:

- W. Rudin, [Principles of Mathematical Analysis, 3rd.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/007054235X)

B. Complex:

- W. Rudin, [Real and Complex Analysis, 3rd.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0070542341)
- L. Ahlfors, [Complex Analysis, 3rd.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0070006571)

**3. Combinatorics:**

- P. J. Cameron, [Combinatorics: Topics, Techniques, Algorithms](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521457610)
- J. H. van Lint and R. M. Wilson, [A Course in Combinatorics, 2nd.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521006015)

**4. Geometry and Topology:**

*This is a vast area with many excellent textbooks in various sub-branches.*

A. Geometry:

For basic geometry I'm not sure if any "standard" / well-known work / textbook is popular or recommended.

B. Topology:

For *General Topology* (i.e. point-set):

J. Munkres, [Topology, 2nd.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131816292)

**5. Number Theory**

Many good introductory books exist, among them:

- G. H. Hardy and E. M. Wright, [An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199219869) (*a classic*; possibly outdated)
- I. Niven, et al., [An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers, 5th.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471625469)
- W. J. LeVeque, [Elementary Theory of Numbers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486663485)

---

Additionally, *Schaum's Outlines* are excellent supplements / study aids / problems and solutions to all the above subjects.

Comment: Are Artin's Algebra and Hoffman and Kunze's Linear Algebra accessible to me?

Comment: @Anirban: I don't know about Artin's Algebra, but Hoffman/Kunze's Linear Algebra should be accessible to you. However, if you're interested in applications, Gilbert Strang's Linear Algebra might be a better fit, possibly followed by Strang's Introduction to Applied Mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

For Analysis, check out the books by walter rudin , u have two versions of the same book , based on sizes.

also u can try thomas's calculus by thomas finney.

If u got ample time, may be you can even try out the books by apostol.

go to complex analysis only once you are done with real analysis.

for complex analysis, i would suggest the book by L V Alfors ( First fields medal winner)

Number theory , use the book - Number theory an introductory course by Ivan Niven, Zuckerman

There are many books available for number theory in the market but this one stands apart.

Comment: I have heard of Rudin's books. Do you mean the Principles of Mathematical Analysis or Real and Complex Analysis?

Comment: I meant he principles of mathematical analysis

Comment: thomas's calculus is too basic to be considered college-level, but the other suggestions are great